Import CSV Bigquery with only 1 header row
I'm importing CSV files from Google Storage into BigQuery using this code:
    LOAD DATA OVERWRITE [DBNAME].[TABLENAME]
FROM FILES (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://xxxx/yyyy/file.csv'],
  field_delimiter = '\t',
  allow_quoted_newlines = true
);

This works very good, but sometimes we haven an empty CSV file. This file will only contain 1 header row. What I would expect is an empty table with the right column names. However, the result is a table with 1 row (the value of the headers) and generated column names like string_field_0, string_field_1, ...
How can I make sure it imports the CSV, creates the table with the headers as column names with 0 rows inside of it?

In the documentation page on Loading CSV data from Cloud Storage, in subsection "CSV header" of section "Schema auto-detection", it is mentioned (emphasis mine),

BigQuery infers headers by comparing the first row of the file with
other rows in the file. If the first line contains only strings, and
the other lines contain other data types, BigQuery assumes that the
first row is a header row. . . . Otherwise, BigQuery assumes the first
row is a data row, and assigns generic column names such as
string_field_1. . . . You might have a CSV file with a header row,
where all of the data fields are strings. In that case, BigQuery will
not automatically detect that the first row is a header. Use the
--skip_leading_rows option to skip the header row. Otherwise, the header will be imported as data. Also consider providing an explicit schema in this case, so that you can assign column names.

You can read about skip_leading_rows and other options (like format, uris, etc.) in the subsection on options of the argument load_option_list of the LOAD DATA statement.
Here's an example of how to use skip_leading_rows while loading a CSV file into a table, from the page about Load statements in GoogleSQL
LOAD DATA INTO mydataset.table1(x INT64, y STRING)
  FROM FILES(
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    format='CSV',
    uris = ['gs://bucket/path/file.csv']
  )


You can always check for empty files before you load them. Another Important thing is to create the Table using the DDL Statement.
CREATE TABLE `DATASET.TABLE_NAME` (
  column_no_1 STRING,
  column_no_2 NUMBER,
  column_no_3 STRING
);

First try to create the temporary table that can generate schema inferred by the file. Then check if the Table contains data along with headers. It it only create the header you can skip it as per your desired logic. Finally clean up by deleting the temporary table.

BigQuery interpret the header row as a data row when no other rows exist. You can avoid this by using the skip_leading_rows option to skip the header row during the load process.
LOAD DATA OVERWRITE [DBNAME].[TABLENAME]
FROM FILES (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://xxxx/yyyy/file.csv'],
  field_delimiter = '\t',
  allow_quoted_newlines = true,
  skip_leading_rows = 1
)
WITH AUTO_DETECT = TRUE;

